# Trouble Deploying a Django App to Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elasticsearch

I know this question has been asked a lot but none of the solutions are working for me. I am trying to Deploy a Django 1.8 web app in elastic beanstalk. It works when Debug is set to true but not when set to false. This is a brand new app so other than changing the debug mode I have not done anything. I have tried:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.elasticbeanstalk.com', 'elasticbeanstalk.com.']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['RDS_HOSTNAME']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.ec2-52-10-0-17.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '.revchip.elasticbeanstalk.com'
    'revchip.elasticbeanstalk.com.'
]
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['revchip.elasticbeanstalk.com', 'ec2-52-10-0-17.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com']
```

With Some solutions it gives a Bad Request 400 error but with some others it does a The requested URL / was not found on this server. such as if I do the ['*'] solution

Comment: I am having the same issue. When I have debug=False, nothing gets served to the page. I refresh it and it loads a blank page. Please let me know if you found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I had the exactly same issue and luckily had it solved by inserting project parent directory into sys.path on `wsgi.py`

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/python/current/app')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'your.settings')
```

hope this helps.